# How to get a group's description with PowerShell

Tags: 2010, groups

I cannot access the description of a group like this:

```
$web = Get-SPWeb "http.//yourUrl"
$web.SiteGroups | %{write-host $_.Name, $_.Description}
```

According to [this](http://www.go4sharepoint.com/Forum/sharepoint-group-description-6717.aspx), the description value is in fact stored as "About Me" in the DB-table AllUserData.

Using the group web service and $SPService.GetGroupCollectionFromWeb() also retreives groups without description.

How to read the description property of an SPGroup?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/968819/change-description-of-a-sharepoint-group/1116049#1116049) holds everything to get the group's description. You need this object:

```
$text = $web.SiteUserInfoList.Fields[($web.SiteUserInfoList.Fields | ?{$_.InternalName -eq "Notes"})]
```

You fetch the group item based on id and extract the description with the internal name

```
$groupItem = $web.SiteUserInfoList.GetItemById($_.Id)
$description = $groupItem[$text.InternalName]
```

The non-pedagogic version of accessing the description field does not deal with my $text variable, and uses this:

```
$description = $groupItem["Notes"]
```

If you are about to display this data you should be aware that this is HTML

Answer (score 0):

Please try the below code, It displays all the group's description.

```
$web = Get-SPWeb "your site URL"
$groups=$web.SiteGroups 
foreach($group in $groups)
{
write-host $group.Description
}
```

Comment: No, I just tried, and did so before, and I know this is what M$ probably thinks should work...BTW: where's the key difference to my script?

Answer (score 0):

As the same that you have to do by C#.
Basically exist a list where SharePoint save this information.
Basically this list is the **SiteUserInfoList** has @StefG wrote.

There are many fancy thing about this list. For more information take a look here: http://salvatoredifaziosharepoint.blogspot.co.uk/2013/08/how-to-retrieve-spgroup-description.html